# Hibernate select query is not returning the latest record from database

Tags: hibernate

I am working on a simple hibernate crud application where I am doing CRUD operation on a table LOCATION.
I am using maven 3.0, hibernate 3.6, oracle 10g, java 8.

I am performing these 4 operations.
1) Insert a row in table Location(successful)
2) Retrieve that row to check the status(successful)
3) Updating one column of the same record(successful. Database is being updated)
4) Retrieve the same row again. Here is the catch. I am not getting the updated state of the row which has already been updated in step 3. I am getting the result which was returned in step 2 retrieval.

Here is my Main class.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        //step 1
        session.beginTransaction();
        saveLocation(session);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        //step 2
        session.beginTransaction();
        retrieveLocation(session);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        //step 3
        session.beginTransaction();
        updateLocation(session);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        //step 4
        session.beginTransaction();
        retrieveLocation(session);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

    private static void saveLocation(final Session session) {
        Location location = new Location();
        location.setZip("751001");
        location.setCity("Bhubaneswar");
        location.setCountry("India");
        location.setRegion("Asia pacific");
        session.save(location);
    }

    private static void retrieveLocation(final Session session) {
        Query query = session.createQuery("from org.bhawani.practice.hibernate.location.Location where zip = :zip");
        query.setParameter("zip", "751001");
        List<Location> locations = query.list();
        for (Location location : locations) {
            System.out.println("City: " + location.getCity());
        }
    }

    private static void updateLocation(final Session session) {
        Query query = session.createQuery(
                "update org.bhawani.practice.hibernate.location.Location set city = :city where zip = :zip");
        query.setParameter("city", "Cuttack");
        query.setParameter("zip", "751001");
        query.executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

Here is my model class Location.java

```
package org.bhawani.practice.hibernate.location;

public class Location {
    private String zip;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String region;

    public Location() {
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

}
```

Here is my hibernate mapping xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
     "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
     "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.bhawani.practice.hibernate.location.Location"
        table="LOCATION">
        <id name="zip" type="string">
            <column name="ZIP" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="city" type="string">
            <column name="CITY" />
        </property>
        <property name="country" type="string">
            <column name="COUNTRY" />
        </property>
        <property name="region" type="string">
            <column name="REGION" />
        </property>
    </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is my table description.

```
Name    Null     Type               
------- -------- ------------------ 
ZIP     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) 
CITY             VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) 
COUNTRY          VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) 
REGION           VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
```

Here is my hibernate config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">hr</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">HR</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="org/bhawani/practice/hibernate/location/Location.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are neither closing nor clearing the session (persistence context) between the queries, that's why the same `Location` instances are fetched from the first-level cache each time.

Furthermore, you are updating the `Location` via an HQL bulk update statement, which does not affect the instances already loaded in memory (first-level cache), as described [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/Development_Guide/About_Bulk_Update_Insert_and_Delete.html):

> Using DML may violate the object/relational mapping and may affect
>   object state. Object state stays in memory and by using DML, the state
>   of an in-memory object is not affected depending on the operation that
>   is performed on the underlying database. In-memory data must be used
>   with care if DML is used.

and [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html):

> Caution should be used when executing bulk update or delete operations
>   because they may result in inconsistencies between the database and
>   the entities in the active persistence context. In general, bulk
>   update and delete operations should only be performed within a
>   transaction in a new persistence con- text or before fetching or
>   accessing entities whose state might be affected by such operations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.